# limited number of classes for MultiOutputClassifier + SVC?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm working on a machine learning problem and I met a limit on the number of classes I can run by using `MultiOutputClassifier` and `SVC`. In particular, the fit fails when the number of classes>14. I follow the example reported in the `MultiOutputClassifier` manual page, but using `SVC` and `n_classes=15`:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_multilabel_classification
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC

X, y = make_multilabel_classification(n_classes=15, random_state=0)
clf = MultiOutputClassifier(SVC()).fit(X, y)
```

This code fails with the following error message:

> "ValueError: The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1 class"

By using `KNeighborsClassifier` it does not fail.
What's wrong? how can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the error message itself because it is misleading. Your problem is that the default value for `n_samples` is set to 100 and when using `n_classes=15`, some classes are not represented in the `y` output at all which is the source of the error. The classifier expects each class to be represented at least once.

Just by changing the `n_samples` to some bigger value, let's say 1000 will "solve" the error because now, every class will be represented.

```
X, y = make_multilabel_classification(n_classes=15, random_state=0, n_samples=1000)
clf = MultiOutputClassifier(SVC()).fit(X, y)
```

Here is simple reproduction case.

Given (5x5) input and (5x5) output (identity matrix), this will work just fine.

```
y = np.eye(5)
x = np.ones((5, 5))
clf = MultiOutputClassifier(SVC()).fit(x, y)
```

Now let's change the first row of the `y` to have `1` in the second column instead (the first class will not be represented anymore)

```
y = np.eye(5)
y[0, 0] = 0
y[0, 1] = 1
x = np.ones((5, 5))
clf = MultiOutputClassifier(SVC()).fit(x, y)
```

This will throw the same error

> ValueError: The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1 class

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, now I understand!